# Symfony 2 Doctrine MongoDB entity listener

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get Entity Listeners work with ODM in Symfony 2.7 but to no avail.

```
 a51.document.listener.store:
    class: A51\FilesystemBundle\EventListener\StoreEntityListener
    tags:
        -  { name: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager, event: postLoad, method: onPostLoad }
    arguments: [@a51.repo.file]
```

and:

```
<?php

namespace A51\FilesystemBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use A51\FilesystemBundle\Document\Store;
use A51\FilesystemBundle\Repository\FileRepositoryInterface;

class StoreEntityListener
{
    /**
     * @var FileRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $fileRepository;

    public function __construct(FileRepositoryInterface $fileRepository)
    {
        $this->fileRepository = $fileRepository;
    }

    public function onPostLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->index($args);
    }

    public function index(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof Store) 
        {
            $entity->setTotalByteSize($this->fileRepository->findSumFilesSizeByStore($entity));
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried pretty much everything I could find in docs but for some reason onPostLoad method does not get called.

Store document gets loaded with ParamConverter:

```
     * @ParamConverter("store", class="A51FilesystemBundle:Store")
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MongoDB listener in my project, but my code it's so different of yours. There's a simpler way, all you must to do it's **import** *DocumentManager* and then you can call it from *construct* to use it on all you listener. I'm gonna show you my code and tell me if this help you ;)

```
namespace AppBundle\OdmListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostPersistEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

class RedundancyListener
{
    /**
     * @var DocumentManager
     */
    private $dm;

    /**
     * @param DocumentManager $odm
     */
    function __construct(DocumentManager $dm)
    {

        $this->dm = $dm;

    }
```

Then inside you can do any queries or updates as you do it in you controller. Also you can use ORM or ODM *CycleEvents* if you import them, like I do in the example.

```
    /**
         * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
         */
        public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
        {
            $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

            if ($entity instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\Example) {

                    $subscriptionHash = $this->getSubscription($entity);

                    $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle\Document\Example')
                        ->update()
                        //->multiple(true)
                        ->field('name')->set($entity->getName())
                        ->field('last_name')->set($entity->getLastName())
                        ->field('mail')->set($entity->getMail())
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->execute();
             }
      }
  }
```